# How to iterate through every word several times in python?

Tags: python

I'm making a script that should take in a set of words in a file, encrypt them in 25 different ways, then output the results to another file.

So what i have so far is a script that takes in all the words, encrypt them only once and outputs the list. I can't figure out how to encrypt each word 25 times (meaning, making 25 new words out of each word)

Here is my code so far:

```
for c in range(len(text)):
    lister = text[c]
    s += 1
    print("Cipher number %s: " % c + encrypt(lister, s))
    output_file.write("\n")
    output_file.write(encrypt(lister, s))
```

text is the file containing the words, and the function encrypt takes in that list, and s is the number of shifts for the encryption, meaning s = 1 is one encryption way, and s = 2 is another way to encrypt the same word. The code right now encrypts all the words in different encryptions since s changes its value each time the for loop goes through a new word

How can i make the for loop change the value of s only after it has encrypted the previous word 25 times at s = 1 to s = 25?

Comment: As far as I understand, 's' is adding either the digit 1 to the text or the digit 1 refers to some cipher which has the key 1? Is that correct? If so, can you increment 's' and run 's' until the incrementation reaches 25?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a nested loop. Simply put, you need to do a task 25 times for each word.

```
for c in range(len(text)):
    lister = text[c]
    for s in range(1, 26): #goes from 1 to 25.
        print("Cipher number %s: " % c + encrypt(lister, s))
        output_file.write("\n")
        output_file.write(encrypt(lister, s))
```

I should also mention that python gives us a much nicer way of iterating through lists using the "in" operator.

```
for lister in text:
    for s in range(1, 26): #goes from 1 to 25.
        print("Cipher set for word ",lister)
        output_file.write("\n")
        output_file.write(encrypt(lister, s))
```

If you need both index numbers while iterating through a list, use enumerate instead.

Comment: You're the man. That's exactly what i was looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a nested loop, inside the current loop you have. Make that loop run 25 times for each time the outer loop iterates, and increase the value of `s` each time the inner loop iterates.

In other words, put the main body of your current loop inside `for s in range(25):`. That, in turn, should go inside `for c in range(len(text)):`. Does this help?